# CMake using the same external library in two projects

Tags: cmake

I have two projects who use the same external library (same version as well)

Using ExternalProject_Add in both project's CMakeLists downloads the lib twice to each of the project's folders and compiles them

Is there a way to download the lib to a shared location and use it on both project?

I'm aiming at saving download time and compile time

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: Not yet, the only way I can think of is doing the ExternalProject_Add higher in the CMake hierarchy

Comment: How about using some protection condition statements? Like `if(TARGET proj-target) skip compilation else()  ExternalProject_Add(proj) endif()`. So that we don't have to change anything in the subproject.

Comment: I think that's a good idea as long as your two projects are nested under the same CMakeLists file.
that way you preserve the ability to compile them separately.